# Installing grub boot on Uefi 64 bit HP LAPTOP

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Could I clarify an installation choice. I am installing Ubuntu 14.04 to an existing W8 installation with 'secure boot' disabled as I could not get the Uefi to pick up the live Dvd. 
There is an existing partition Sda2 FAT 'Efi System' set up by the original installation. I was encouraged to create a new 'Bios Boot' Sda5 1MiB partition and pointed the installer to 'Sda'.
The boot sequence is not automatic and is a mess of selections to eventually get to choose 'boot from hard drive' which then picks up Grub.

Would it be correct if I deleted the new Bios boot partition on the hope that grub will install on the original 'Efi Syatem' (using Rescatux live Dvd)?

Comments would be appreciated,

Comment: You should be installing in UEFI modem, so won't need the grub-bios partition (sda5).  Did you hashcheck with md5sum the 14.04 iso?

Comment: ubfan1, Hi, I used a magazine DVD so no checks were made. The original Bootup did not show the DVD as an option to choose, ie did not recognise a bootable system on DVD. My only option therefore was to choose 'legacy' mode and the the DVD was picked up. But am not certain I made the right choices during the install.

Comment: So the legacy install put no UEFI bootloaders into the EFI partition's /EFI/ubuntu, instead setting up the Master Boot Block on the device, and if a gpt disk, copied the rest of the grub core image into the 1M partition flagged grub-bios.  You might be able to boot Ubuntu, but certainly not Windows in legacy mode.  Boot-repair might be able to switch you back to UEFI mode (or you could copy the shimx64.efi.signed and/or grubx64.efi.signed to the /EFI/ubuntu  directory.

Comment: Thanks again,your assistance is appreciated. There is no /ubuntu in sda3, EFI. I cannot read the Bios boot partition made on the ubuntu install, I can boot either system thro' Grub by choosing the 'boot from hard drive'(esc +F9) which takes me to grub screen. After sorting out some errors om W8 doing some MS chkdsk or update, I used 'Rescatux' to restore grub.  So I do get to choose either OS thro Grub but it is an indirect messy path and not a default option preferred. Would I have a cleaner boot if I deleted the Sda5 Bios Boot partition and directed grub to sda2 the FAT-EFI partition?

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations on getting the boot to work.  Let me describe the boot process a little, so you can decide what if anything you want to do about the boot order in the grub menu, which is really another question (answered elsewhere here).
  Legacy boot uses simple firmware that knows how to start executing at the first block of a device (the Master Boot Block or MBR).  This is grub-pc after you install it -- a small binary blob, which needs more code to do much (the second bigger binary blob called core.img, but since both binary blobs are not even in a filesystem, the concept of a "name" is misleading.  On an MSDOS type partition, the second binary blob fits into the partition structure right after the MBR, but on a GPT partitioning, there is no room there, so you need another place, the small 1M partition with the grub-bios flag.  Again, what's in this grub-bios partition is just a binary blob, no filesystem, so not much for you to "read".
  Enter UEFI, with smarter firmware.  Now the firmware knows about FAT filesystems, and can actually be set up to select a file in that type of filesystem -- no more binary blobs to worry about, just files.  You can use any standard file-copy mechanism to move these files, no more special tools needed to write binary blobs into selected block locations on the disk.   Now the location of this FAT filesystem for booting is any partition with the boot flag.  (However, on the current crop of hugh disks, maybe it's still good to keep it near the beginning of the disks).  All the bootloaders you want (space allowing), can go into the filesystem, which uses the standard directory/subdirectory method to keep them separate.  The Ubuntu bootloaders go into the /EFI/ubuntu (kubuntu, ... whatever) directory.  There is really only the new grubx64.efi, but it comes in both a cryptographically signed and unsigned version. Canonical signs the grubx64.efi, which basically still cannot run because the firmware only comes with the ability to run Microsoft signed code (when secure boot is enabled).  So Canonical paid Microsoft to sign a tiny little program which can only run grubx64.efi -- that's the shimx64.efi.  Nothing in this UEFI description precludes the use of the old MBR boot mechanism -- and that's exactly what the live media uses, both of them.
  I'd suggest reading more about UEFI, and look up the grub menu reordering if you want to change the grub defaults. Good Luck.

Comment: Many thanks again, it is certainly a new field for me which I hope to get more familiar.

Comment: I will study your remarks closely.  I did get another problem after windows zapped some settings again, this time I used Boot-repar-disk, It was a painful process but did resolve itself on the second run.  Now if I switch on I immediatley get the grub options (and suddenly a lot of them) included in which is Ubuntu default and hidden in the list is W8.  Resolved in Legacy mode!  I tried Secure boot mode but any option returns error 'Selected boot image did not authenticate'